# How to collect List<String> to List<String> using streams in java?

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I have `listData (List<String>)` and a `getList` method that accepts a String as an argument (e.g. `"java"`) and returns a `List<String>` (e.g. `["j","a","v","a"]`). I need to collect these lists to a single List. I tried `addAll`, and it works fine:

```
List<String> listData = Arrays.asList("java","Stream","laMbdA");
List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

listData.stream()
        .map(this::getList)  // acccepts String as an argument and returns List<String>
        .forEach(resultList::addAll);
```

If I try `Collectors.toList()`, I am getting a `List<List<String>>`

```
 listData.stream()
         .map(this::getList)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there any method in `Collectors` which I could use instead of `addAll`?

Comment: @flakes he did, it returns the string as a list. Try flatmap from the stream api

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `flatMap`:

```
List<String> resultList =
    listData.stream()
            .flatMap(s -> getList(s).stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Simple explanation of what flatMap does here: https://byexample.xyz/java/8/map/#flatmap-examples

Answer (score 3):

An extension to Eran's answer using method references only. since you're using method references within your post, you could also do the same and just chain `flatMap` on top of your `map` operation.

```
   List<String> resultSet =
                 listData.stream()
                         .map(this::getList)
                         .flatMap(List::stream)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

I think below is gonna help you. 
Giving some explain, the "map" return List, which is going to be an element of the "resultList". So you just need to collect them returned by "map" function as list, using `toList` collector.
Hope that help you.

```
public class ListStreamQ {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> listData = Arrays.asList("java", "Stream", "laMbdA");
    List<Collection<String>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    resultList = listData.stream()
            .map(ListStreamQ::getList)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(resultList);
}

static List<String> getList(String word){
    return Arrays.asList(word.split(""));
}
```

}